# 'decimal.DivisionUndefined' error thrown when creating model before children models

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I try to create a model that uses children models before making these children models, I keep getting error: class 'decimal.DivisionUndefined'. I do not understand why this error is being thrown or how to resolve it.

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    sub_value1: DecimalField = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, null=True)

    class Meta:
    @property
    def children(self):
        children = []
        for child in Child.objects.all():
            if child.parent_id == self.id:
                children.append(child)
        return children

    @property
    def main_value(self):
        try:
            main_value = self.sub_value1 / self.sub_value2
            return round(main_value, 2)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return 0
        except TypeError:
            return None

    @property
    def sub_value2(self):
        local_sub_value2 = 0
        for child in self.children:
            local_sub_value2 += child.sub_value_2_of_child
        return round(local_sub_value_2, 2)
```

When I create this model without any children created yet, I expect the children property to return an empty array. Therefore sub_value2 should be 0, therefore main_value should throw a ZeroDivisionError which I am handling.

However, I keep getting the following error from django:

```
[<class 'decimal.DivisionUndefined'>]
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: Note separately, your `children` method seems unnecessarily inefficient. Why don't you have a ForeignKey and just do `self.child_set.all()`?

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman, I didn't see that question before. It solved my issue. Thanks aswell for the suggestion to use self.child_set.all(), I didn't know about it. I implemented it now :)